# How to log HTTP requests made by Quarkus GraphQL Client?

Tags: debugging, graphql, quarkus

I'm running into serious problems trying to get Quarkus to show the HTTP requests being made by the typesafe GraphQL client.

The project contains an interface GraphQL client definition `com.example.MyApi` and I have tried the following configurations in `application.properties` without success:

```
quarkus.log.category."io.smallrye.graphql".level=FINEST
quarkus.log.category."io.vertx".min-level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."com.example.MyApi".level=FINEST
```

When that failed, I downloaded Requestly and subsequently mitmproxy in order to capture requests in the proxy, but it appears that `http.proxyHost`, `http.proxyPort`, `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort` are all ignored by Quarkus somehow.

Has anybody gotten either logging of the actual HTTP requests generated by the typesafe GraphQL client to work or proxying of the outgoing requests so they can be viewed by another tool?

Comment: Have you tried access logging ? 

See this link: https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#configuring-http-access-logs

Comment: This only configures logging of incoming requests, not outgoing requests as specified in the question.

Comment: I don’t think there is a default configuration for logging responses since this can lead to security issues like data breach. 

If you need one you should do it via custom filter.

Comment: Comment is Serkan is good enough. No logging for outgoing HTTP (responses). The question is not rationale.

Answer (score -2):

The request is logged in trace mode here: https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-graphql/blob/19c3acf6eb2361d2aa4f03a1ae839813f0bae986/client/implementation-vertx/src/main/java/io/smallrye/graphql/client/vertx/typesafe/VertxTypesafeGraphQLClientProxy.java#L303C13-L303C19

So setting the appropriate logger to trace should give you the request:

`quarkus.log.category."io.smallrye.graphql.client".level=TRACE` should do it (see https://quarkus.io/guides/logging)

Comment: This doesn't result in any logging of requests taking place in Quarkus 3.4.1

Comment: Then I suggest creating a reproducer and ping us on zulip or GitHub discussions